# Should labels in tikz / pgfplots / etc. have serifs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fonts, typography, sans-serif

By default, diagrams in tikz and pgfplots inherit the style of the surrounding document, which is a good thing.  However, I've read that serifs are good for large bodies of printed text (the main text of the document), whereas sans-serif is more suitable for headings.  What is a good choice for labels in diagrams such as drawn with tikz and pgfplots, and why?  What is the tradition here?

```
\tikzset{every node/.append style={font=\sffamily}} % yes or no?
```

Although I realise that *good* may be subjective, it appears that typographers often have strong reasons to favour a particular style.

Related questions:

- *[When to use serif and when to use sans serif font family](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7562/8141)*
- *[When to use bold, italics, small caps, typewriter etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5008/8141)*